# Laravel mix npm run hot error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I'm starting to study `VUEJS` with `Hot Module Replacement (or HMR)`, and I did a clean install of Laravel v5.8, and following the instructions in the documentation of the Laravel Mix -- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix -- everything looks very simple, however, when running the `npm run hot`, error is displayed in the browser console.

Apparently it is functional, but I'm not sure if this is expected behavior or if in fact it is an error and that needs some adjustment or parameterization.

But the interesting thing is that if I run `npm run dev`, no error is displayed.

**versions**

```
# php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.37

# npm -v
6.13.4

# node -v
v12.16.1

# yarn -v
1.21.1
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    hmrOptions: {
        host: 'vueapp.lab',
        port: '8080'
    }
 });

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

[image: npm run hot error]

Comment: Can you include your `app.js` code especially at line 726

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will test.

Comment: I also facing this problem on fresh Laravel 7.3 install. This is related to laravel-mix, afaik it's related to extract-text-webpack-plugin. No workaround for this atm.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can anyone of you resolved this issue. Please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is  the app.scss is compiled by default by webpack and it is linked as a resource in mix.config.js.

So removing app.scss compilation from your mix.config.js and import it to your main .vue file (default is App.vue) hmr will do the trick.

In your main vue file add tag style like this:

```
 <style lang="scss">
    @import 'path/to/app.scss';
 </style>
```